# Mapping JPA entity with composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to map an entity with a composite key, but I need the composite key to be the id of other entity and a String, this is my class at the moment but I believe there may be something wrong.

```
@Entity
public class Permission implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String permission;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_permission_role_id"))
    private Role role;

.....
```

Comment: I am not an expert in JPA, but assuming the "Role" Entity table has a "permission" column, this would do:  `@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "permission")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Role role;`

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ID in role is a simple Integer, you might use something like:

```
public class PermissionPK implements Serializable {
    private String permission;
    private Integer role;
}
```

And then add the @IdClass annotation to your entity:

```
@IdClass(PermissionPK.class)
@Entity
public class Permission implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String permission;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  private Role role;
}
```

This will allow you to uses EmployeePK instances in find operations, but it isn't needed for anything else.

Comment: So the IDClass is only used for find operations?

Comment: There might be an edge case with further deriving an id and using embeddedId mappings, but for the most part, yes, it is only required for the JPA the find operation.